# AngularJS ng-view commented out and no error happend

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to use ng-view in angularjs. I created 1 html files in a folder named detail.html. And I want to load it into my index.html ng-view tag. But the ng-view is commented. And no error happend.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uBv0.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *"the ng-view is commented"*? Please provide a [mcve] and don't put code into images...put it into the question itself. Can't copy code from images and it is harder to read than in syntax highlighted text within the question itself

Answer (score 0):

It'll not show error if you comment out any code inside html. So if you want different views along with manipulation based on `$routeParams` here's working example.

http://embed.plnkr.co/A67EbeUHS0QgiJksvsel/